# Android: Passing TextView as parameter to external function returns nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass a TextView as a parameter to an external class to perform some functionality but I'm hitting a NullPointerException each time.

**Activity.java**

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
Log.v("", "Contents: " + tv.getText().toString()); // This works fine
externalClass.addViewToList(tv);
externalClass.printViewContents(tv.getText().toString());
```

**External Class**

```
public List<View> _views;

// This doesn't work
public void addViewToList(View v) {
    try {
        this._views.add(v);
        Log.v("", "Added " + v.getId() + " to list");
    }
    catch(NullPointerException ex) {
        Log.e("", "NullPointerException when adding view to list");
    }
}

// But this works fine
public void printViewContents(String contents) {
    Log.v("",contents);
}
```

So I know the view has been found in the layout.xml and it has been initialized, my question is how do I pass a View from my Activity to an external class.

Thanks

---

Edit

Forgot that Lists need to be initalised as ArrayList

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your _views list isnt initialized i.e youre trying to write data to null.
to solve this you need to write:

```
public List<View> _views = new List<>();
```

instead of just:

```
public List<View> _views;
```

for less headache I recommend that you work with an array list instead:

```
public ArrayList<View> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

now it will work :)

Answer (score 1):

Your " _views"  list did not  initialized. see below it work.

public List _views = new ArrayList();

Thank you.